# Deep comparison of objects' properties of same type

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, comparison

I'm trying to compare two objects of the same type. What I want to achieve at the end, is a new object with only the properties that are different.

For example:

```
type A = {
    id: string;
    col: number;
    enabled: true;
    obj: {
        b: number;
    }
}

const a: A = {
    id: "ddd",
    col: 4,
    enabled: true,
    obj: {
        b: 4
    }
}

const b: A = {
    id: "dde",
    col: 4,
    enabled: true,
    obj: {
        b: 3
    }
}

const c = () => Object.values(a).reduce((bef, aft, i) => {
    const valuesB = Object.values(b);
    const keyB = Object.keys(b)[i];
    return valuesB[i] === aft ? { ...bef } : { keyB: valuesB[i], ...bef }
}, {})
```

With my logic above I was able to get a new object like:

```
{
  "keyB": "dde"
}
```

It got the value right but the key wrong and also ignored the fact that the nested object property has different values. I'm a bit stuck and out of ideas.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to see if the nested object is identical?  Do you want `{obj: {}}` or just `{}`?   Hmm you already accepted another answer but I'm not sure it's doing what you actually want, nor is the typing necessarily correct.  I'm happy to write up [my version](https://tsplay.dev/mbnA2m) as an answer but even if you want to keep accepting the existing one you should ask about these edge cases and the typing.

Comment: I didn't spot that slight "mistake: in the other answer, I would want `{}` rather than `{obj:{}}`. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the incorrect key, you'd just have to add brackets around `keyB` to use the value of the variable as key: `{ [keyB]: valueB, ...bef }`

About the missing nested object, that's a bit more complicated but here's a solution:

```
const diff = <T>(obj1: T, obj2: T): Partial<T> =>
    Object.values(obj1).reduce((bef, aft, i) => {
        const valueB = Object.values(obj2)[i];
        const keyB = Object.keys(obj2)[i];
        if (valueB instanceof Object) {
            const delta = diff(valueB, aft);
            return Object.keys(delta).length > 0 ? { [keyB]: diff(valueB, aft), ...bef } : bef;
        }
        return valueB === aft ? bef : { [keyB]: valueB, ...bef };
    }, {});

const c = (): Partial<A> => diff(a, b);
```

You have to check each field of the nested object separately. That's what the recursion is for.

I also added typings to the functions. `Partial<A>` is a copy of `A` but makes all fields optional.

The result is:

```
{
    "obj": {
        "b": 4
    },
    "id": "dde"
}
```

Comment: That is spot on, didn't think about using recursion in this scenario and silly me for the [] in keyB, thanks a lot

Comment: In this version, if `obj` is identical you get `{obj: {}}` instead of `{}`, but it's not clear to me that's the right approach.  Also note that you are not producing `Partial<T>` but something like `DeepPartial<T>` (e.g., `type DeepPartial<T> = {[K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T>}`) because properties and subproperties might themselves be missing properties.